# How to fix hydro ros in ubuntu12.04

Tags: boost, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I falsely tried to update boost to be libboost1.55-dev by using PPA as [this link](http://choorucode.com/2013/12/27/how-to-upgrade-the-boost-library-on-ubuntu/) . This caused unexpected breakdowns. Firstly, many lines with "Removing ros-hydro-xxx, Removing ros-groovy-xxx" (My OS is with two versions of ROS) came out and couldn't be stopped by "`ctril+ c`". Finally, a red circle with a white line in the middle of it came up in the upper-right corner of desktop of Ubuntu. Then luckily I openned "Ubuntu Software Center" and it disappear the red circle by automatically repairing some missing packages. The reason is same to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/170406/ros-hydro-and-boost-148/) about boost in hydro.

However, when I want to compile some packages by `catkin_make`, it prompted that some fundamental packages couldn't be found such as `std_msgs`. So I have to repair the ros-hydro. I don't know how to do. Should I re-install hydro ros by the instruction for [hydro installation](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu) from ROS tutorial with uninstallation?

I have tried to uninstall hydro ros by [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/28589/uninstall-ros/), but the terminal prompted

> E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro

or

> E: Unable to locate package hydro

Hopefully any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195895/how-to-fix-hydro-ros-in-ubuntu12.04/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to remove the conflicting packages which you installed (and caused the uninstallation of the ros packages) Once those are removed/downgraded to the older versions you will be able to install hydro the standard way.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0